# How to trim white space in MySQLdb using python

Tags: python, mysql-python, strip

I have a web form taking user data and putting it into a mysql database. I need to trim leading and trailing blanks/spaces. I currently am utilizing the strip() method, but it only trims them for the fields, NOT for the mysql database.

My code is:

```
first_name = first_name.strip()
last_name = last_name.strip()
```

so on and so forth. It strips it perfectly fine for the webpage, but not when it is entered into the SQL database. The spaces still exist. How do I remove them?

EDIT:

```
        db = MySQLdb.connect("localhost","user","pass","db_name")
        cursor = db.cursor()
                cursor.execute("Select * FROM registrants")
                cursor.execute("INSERT INTO registrants VALUES( " + "'" + first_name + "'" + ", " + "'" + last_name + "'" + ");")
        db.commit()
        db.close()
```

Comment: please clarify your question, how do you insert data into the database? is the data already there?

Comment: Could you paste the code that inserts them into the database?

Comment: My apologies, I thought I had, it slipped my mind :)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It could be a scope issue.

If the stripping occurs in a different scope (ex: first_name is a global variable and the strip() occurs in a function) then you will not benefit from it in another scope (if the insert is happening in another function for example).

Have you tried this for a test:

```
cursor.execute("INSERT INTO registrants VALUES( " + "'" + first_name.strip() + "'" + ", " + "'" + last_name.strip() + "'" + ");")
```

btw, how do you know there's a space in the db? There could be an issue with the way the data is retrieved or displayed..

Comment: Because when you look in the database it shows "                                       information" if spaces are entered. And because I only do it once, it's not in a function :).

Comment: Can you do a SELECT LENGTH(first_name) and compare to the actual length of the first name?  There could be a mysql client display issue.

Answer (score 0):

I think you should be passing the values into the INSERT differently

```
cursor.execute("INSERT INTO registrants (fname, lname) VALUES (%s, %s)", (first_name, last_name)
```

I'm not sure if that's where you're getting the whitespace, but it opens you up to sql injection so it's bad form to put the variables straight into the query.